# No Data Values in TWI Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have derived Topographic Wetness Index (TWI)/CTI with ArcGIS 10.3 using 30m DEM resolution. Earlier, it was propagating negative values which were mainly confined to ridges. I have restructured the 'Raster Calculator' expression as below and got rid of negative values.

Ln(("Flow_acc"+ 1 ) * 900/"Tan_SlopeRad")

The below process diagram would acquaint you about steps I have taken to arrive at the positive integer values. 
[image: Process Flow Diagram]

and the resultant image clearly indicates values having 'No Data'. These values are mainly confined to Zero Degree Slope within River. 
[image: Resultant TWI Image]

Now, How would I deal with values having ''No Data'???

Comment: There is a very good thread on computing TWI at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90064 .

Answer (score 1):

Zero slope will lead to an infinitely high TWI value, as described in the answer to a similar question ([Getting Negative Topographic Wetness Index (TWI) values in SAGA GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104543/getting-negative-topographic-wetness-index-twi-values-in-saga-gis)).
This is what leads to the NoData values you see. As far as I know, TWI is used as an indicator for wetness conditions in soils, so probably looking at locations right within a river bed won't make sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add a small value such as 0.0001 to the "Tan_SlopeRad" raster to eliminate any undefined values produced by ln(0). This is the same reason you add one to the flow accumulation.

Ln(("Flow_acc"+ 1 ) * 900/("Tan_SlopeRad")+ 0.0001)